# Given a for loop that iterates x times, in terms of algorithm costing is it (x+1)?

Tags: algorithm

I am studying out of the CLRS book and the first example of learning big-O analysis involves a for loop that goes from the second element of the array A up to the final element (page 26), and yet it attributes a time cost to this line as "n".

I do not understand why it isn't n-1. If I have an array A of size 5 (n=5), and my for loop goes from A[1] to A[4], that's a total number of 4 iterations, or n-1.

Is it actually a cost of n because it needs to do one final check to make sure it exits the for loop or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they are trying to demonstrate just what Big-O analysis is all about - it's about the "Big" picture. The usual mathematical explanation is something along the lines of: given sufficiently large values of n, the addition or subtraction of constant terms is immaterial to the analysis of algorithmic complexity.

In simple terms, if an array contains demographic information on the citizens of a country like the US, the array is over 300,000,000 elements in size. When comparing algorithms, would you care if the algorithm did 299,999,999 computations vs 300,000,000 computations?

You can also think of it as rounding, where insignificantly small numbers are trimmed off for simplicity and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

When doing Big-O notation, O(n) and O(n - 1) are the same thing essentially. As n reaches infinity, O(n) and O(n - 1) are approximately the same speed. the -1 is negligible. Big O analysis typically examines the complexity of a function as the parameter approaches infinity.

Comment: I understand that what matters is moreso the order of magnitude (the degree) of the polynomial/etc that describes the runtime, but I am still trying to map out the iteration counts correctly.

Comment: That is wise as it is not uncommon on academic tests to be asked to count exactly how many computations are performed, but such exact counts depend on non-standard rules. Sometimes 'they' want you to count all comparisons but not assignments, sometimes floating point calculations are counted differently or sepparately...etc. But for Big-O analysis, you generally don't worry about such details.

Comment: Your iteration count is correct (disregarding that the for loop has to make an extra comparison to test the exit condition), as the body of the loop will only run n - 1 times. This is irrelevant to Big-O notation however.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of big-O as being an exact count of the number of iterations. The run-time of your loop is proportional to n. In your example, if you double the number of elements in your array then your runtime will also approximately double. If it helps, always think of what would happen if you drastically increase n.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a for loop that processes `n-1` elements of an array is O(n-1), but it also is O(n).   Consider the [formal definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition):

> `f(x) = O(g(x))` if and only if there exists a positive real number `M` and a real number `x0` such that `|f(x)| ≤ M·|g(x)|` for all `x > x_0`.

It is clear that if constants `M` and `x0` work with `g(x)=x-1`, then  `M` and `x0` will also work with `g(x)=x`.

In big-O notation like `O(g(x))`, **it is customary to ignore lower-order terms of a polynomial g(x)** because as `x` grows large, the leading term always will dominate.  More specifically, if the first lower-order term is of negative sign (as it is with `g(x)=x-1`), we don't need to find new values of `M` and `x0`.  If that term is of positive sign, multiplying `M` by the second term's coefficient gives an `M` that works with the second term removed.  This is explained at more length in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Complexity analysis is used to reason about how a computation will behave *in general*. One way it does it is by reasoning about larger and larger input values (going to infinity).

Lets assume your actual computation is some function **f(n) = 3n + 10**

Now let there be *another* function, **g(n) = 5n + 15**

As **n** tends to infinity and you plot the two functions together, the ratio between them tends to a constant. So functions whose ratios tend to a constant are considered to be of similar complexity, and belong to the same *complexity class*.

**f(n)** belongs to the class of **O(n)**, just like **g(n)**.  Edit: A clarification. This is what people generally mean when they talk about complexity in informal settings. To get a deeper understanding of all the different types of asymptotes, please look at the link at the end of this answer.

Now, on the other hand, if **g(n) = 2^n**, then the ratio  between them does *not* tend to a constant, and hence, they will not be in the same complexity class.

As an exercise for yourself, think about how the ratios of **f(n) = log_2(n)** and **g(n) = log_3(n)** will work.

A final note: big-Oh has a stricter definition. It is considered to be an *upper* bound. So, if your function is a constant, like **f(n) = 5**, **f** will still be **O(n)**. You should look into [the whole family of asymptotic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Related_asymptotic_notations) to get a deeper understanding.